# How to auto publish media items created after running the Sharepoint connect module?

Tags: publishing, sharepoint-connect

I am using Sharepoint connect module to pull in documents from Sharepoint. Currently, I have written a scheduled task to publish the items at a specific time.

Is there a way to auto publish the files that are created once the connector has finished downloading all the files?

Comment: Is there a specific field you can determine in which the file is now ready for publish? You could write a Powershell script to query those items based on some specified criteria and call the publish API.

Comment: specific field would be to check if the media blob exists. the issue i faced was, i wasn't able to figure out when the connector has actually finished downloading all the files. The items are created but behind the scene download is happening. i will take a look at powershell solution.

Comment: You could use this script to help you determine if the media item has a blob available. https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/edf8154f8fb4b8d2636390ba76707a48

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:[sharepoint_connector_module_installation_and_configuration_guide.pdf](http://sharepoint_connector_module_installation_and_configuration_guide)

1.3 Publish media files changes made on a SharePoint server
In order to incrementally publish changes in the media files updated on the SharePoint server, you
should make the following changes in the /App_Config/Include/sharepoint.config file:

1. Add the following attribute to the configuration element:
   xmlns:x=http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/
2. add the following code to the  section:

1"
type="Sitecore.Modules.SharePoint.Pipelines.LoadSharepointItems, Sitecore.Modules.SharePoint"
/>

If you use Smart or Full publishing, you don't need to make any configuration changes.

Comment: the correct config changes : <pipelines>
 <publish>
 <processor x:before="*[1]" type="Sitecore.Modules.SharePoint.Pipelines.LoadSharepointItems, Sitecore.Modules.SharePoint"/>
 </publish>
</pipelines>